# Word Interop and getting page count

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

I know in VBA, within a document, I can get page count using `ActiveDocument.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)`, But I can't find an equivalent of it in VB.Net using [`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.aspx).
Is there, perhaps another way I can attain the quantity of pages in a document?

```
Public Class Window
    'set form level declarations
    Dim appPath As String
    Dim objWordApp As New Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim errorPosition As String
    Private Sub Window_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        objDoc = objWordApp.ActiveDocument
        With objDoc
           pages = .ActiveDocument.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
        End With
        objDoc = Nothing
     End Sub
     objWordApp = Nothing
 End Class
```

Comment: WdInformation.wdNumberOfPagesInDocument ?

Comment: The `Microsoft.Office.Interop` namespace reflects the API provided by Office VBA (as close as possible), so basically anything that is possible in VBA can also be done in .NET using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop` namespace. Where exactly are you stuck / having problems with? Is it getting the `ActiveDocument`? In that case: You can get the `ActiveDocument` from the [`Word.Application` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.activedocument.aspx).

Comment: @bassfader I've tried that, but can't get it to work.  I'll post some of my code.

Comment: I think I got it.  `pages = .Application.ActiveDocument.Range.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)`

Comment: `pages = objDoc.ComputeStatistics(WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages, False)`, give that a shot...

Comment: @Codexer thanks but I already got it with my previous post.

Answer (score 3):

A way is to get last page number:

```
lastPageNumber = objDoc.Words.Last.Information[Wd.WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Office.Interop.Word Verion 15.0.0

you can try paginate. like this.

```
objWordApp.Options.Pagination = true;
objWordApp.ActiveDocument.Repagenate();
```

And Then
DocumentFormat.OpenXml Version 2.12.3

```
using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, false))
{ document.ExtentedFilePropertuesPart.Properties.Pages.Text }
```

Answer (score -2):

When you code in VBA, the namespace of the parent application (Word, Excel, etc.) is obvious, so constants such as wdNumberOfPagesInDocument have definitions. With Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word you need to provide the namespace information; for example:

```
...
With objDoc
    pages = .Range.Information(Word.WdInforma‌​tion.wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
End With
....
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with this post but it's been answered in the comments above.
`pages = .Application.ActiveDocument.Range.Information(Word.WdInforma‌​tion.wdNumberOfPages‌​InDocument)`